# How to include MCR and reference a MATLAB assembly in a .NET Http Trigger Azure Function?

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, azure, docker

I am currently working on a proof of concept project using Azure Functions, .NET and Docker to create an HttpTrigger Azure Function that makes use of the MagicSquareComp.dll assembly created in the following tutorial:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/gs/create-a-dotnet-application-with-matlab-code.html

I was able to create a generic .NET Azure Function following the tutorial below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=nodejs

I tried to combine the technologies used in both of these tutorials to create an Azure Function that will print out a magic square. I was able to get this functionality for an HttpTrigger Azure Function to work in both my local Windows environment and an Ubuntu 18.04 VM after installing the MATLAB runtime and configuring things correctly. However, when I attempt to use a docker file and run the Azure function from a docker container using the docker build and docker run commands, I encounter the following error:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function:
MyHttpTrigger ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MagicSquareComp.Class1' 
threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
'MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCR' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The 
type initializer for 'MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWArray' threw an exception. ---> 
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'mclmcrrt9_7.dll' or one of its dependencies. 
In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: 
libmclmcrrt9_7.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The docker container I am using is a Linux container and I have installed the MATLAB runtime on it exactly how I installed it on my Ubuntu 18.04 VM and set the environment variables in the exact same way. I have made sure the MWArray.dll and MagicSquareComp.dll are in the /home/site/wwwroot/bin/ directory. I tried copying the MATLAB runtime folder to /home/site/wwwroot/bin/runtimes/. None of these seem to have any impact. I still receive the same error when I attempt to run from the Docker file.

Below is the code I used in the docker file:

```
# FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS installer-env 



# COPY . /src/dotnet-function-app 

# RUN cd /src/dotnet-function-app && \ 

#     mkdir -p /home/site/wwwroot && \ 

#     dotnet publish *.csproj --output /home/site/wwwroot 





FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS installer-env 

RUN apt-get -qq update && \ 

    apt-get -qq install -y nodejs && \ 

    apt-get -qq install -y npm && \ 

    npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools && \ 

    apt-get -qq install -y curl && \ 

    apt-get -qq install -y wget && \ 

    apt-get -qq install -y unzip && \ 

    curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash && \ 

    wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb && \ 

    dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb && \ 

    apt-get -qq update && \ 

    apt-get -qq install -y apt-transport-https && \ 

    apt-get -qq update && \ 

    apt-get -qq install -y dotnet-sdk-2.1 && \ 

    mkdir /mcr-install && \ 

    mkdir /opt/matlab_runtime && \ 

    cd /mcr-install && \ 

    wget https://ssd.mathworks.com/supportfiles/downloads/R2019b/Release/3/deployment_files/installer/complete/glnxa64/MATLAB_Runtime_R2019b_Update_3_glnxa64.zip && \ 

    unzip -q MATLAB_Runtime_R2019b_Update_3_glnxa64.zip && \ 

    ./install -destinationFolder /opt/matlab_runtime -agreeToLicense yes -mode silent && \ 

    cd && \ 

    rm -rf /mcr-install 



COPY . /src/dotnet-function-app 

RUN cd /src/dotnet-function-app && \ 

    mkdir -p /home/site/wwwroot && \ 

    dotnet publish *.csproj --output /home/site/wwwroot && \ 

    chmod 777 /home/site/wwwroot/bin/MWArray.dll && \ 

    chmod 777 /home/site/wwwroot/bin/MagicSquareComp.dll && \ 

    cp -rf /opt/matlab_runtime /home/site/wwwroot/bin/runtimes 



# To enable ssh & remote debugging on app service change the base image to the one below 

# FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:2.0-appservice  

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:2.0 

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \ 

    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true 



ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/matlab_runtime/v97/runtime/glnxa64:/opt/matlab_runtime/v97/bin/glnxa64:/opt/matlab_runtime/v97/sys/os/glnxa64:/opt/matlab_runtime/v97/extern/bin/glnxa64 



ENV XAPPLRESDIR=/opt/matlab_runtime/v97/X11/app-defaults 



COPY --from=installer-env ["/home/site/wwwroot", "/home/site/wwwroot"]
```

The MagicSquareComp.dll was generated using MATLAB running on Windows. It doesn't seem like this would cause an issue though since I was able to get the Azure function to run and correctly reference both the MagicSquareComp.dll and MWArray.dll in a Linux VM.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
'MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCR' threw an exception. ` Are you sure all the assemblies have been loaded?

Comment: I have included Assembly.Load("MWArray") and Assembly.Load("MagicSquareComp") in the function code to try to make sure both of these assemblies get loaded. However, I still receive the same error. Is there a good way to see what assemblies get loaded when running the azure function from a docker container?